how do I find all $k \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$ for a given sequence without using approximations
I have a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of positive terms defined by the recurrence relation
$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \left(\frac{2n}{2n + k + 4}\right)^{2n},
$
where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \neq -4$. I need to determine all values of $k$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$.
I would like to avoid using Taylor series approximations, binomial approximations.
Ratio-test, cauchy's root-test aswell as euler limit and subsequences are the tools that have been taught, how should I proceed with this problem?

Since I am unfamiliar with the topic, the following idea might well fail to solve the problem: Anyway, my first try would be to let $~r~$ be any fixed (but unspecified) element in $~\Bbb{R^+},~$ and try to determine $~\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left{ ~n \times ~\left[ ~log(n) - \log(n-r) ~\right] ~\right}.$

Have you tried the ratio test?

The sequence $(1 +\frac{1}{n})^n$ is strictly increasing and tends to $e$.  The sequence $(1 -\frac{1}{n})^n$ is strictly decreasing and tends to $e^{-1}$.  With these two facts we can answer the question.  I'll develop the argument for $k < -4$ only.  The other case is similar.
If $k < -4$, setting $a = -k -4 > 0$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{2n}{2n +k +4}\right)^{2n}
= \left(\frac{2n +k +4 -(k +4)}{2n +k +4}\right)^{2n}
= \left(1 +\frac{a}{2n -a}\right)^{2n}
= \left(
\left(1 +\frac{a}{2n -a}\right)^{\frac{2n -a}{a}}
\right)^{\frac{2an}{2n -a}} \longrightarrow e^a.
$$
Hence there exists an integer $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$ we have
$$
\frac{a_{n +1}}{a_n}
= \left(\frac{2n}{2n +k +4}\right)^{2n} > e^a -\epsilon > 1.
$$
We conclude that $a_n$ goes to infinity with $n$.
Remark. I assume that $a_0 > 0$ and that $k$ is such that $2n +k +4$ is never zero when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
